# How to access these rates on my python tkinter code without TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

import tkinter as tk
import requests

class MyApp:
    def **init**(self):
        self.master=tk.Tk()
        self.master.geometry('600x400+200+150')
        self.master.config(bg='#008080')
        self.frame=tk.Frame(self.master, bg='#008080')
        self.frame.pack()

```
    RATES = {
        "Australian Dollar":1.4099,
        "Brazilian Real":3.7927,
        "Canadian dollar":1.3375,
        "Switzerland Franc":0.9964,
        "China Yuan":6.7131,
        "Euro":0.8845,
        "United Kingdom Pound":0.763,
        "Hungarian Forint":279.337,
        "Indian Rupees":68.98,
        "Japanese Yen":110.5194,
        "Kenyan shilling":100.6989,
        "Korean Won":1133.5973,
        "Malawian Kwacha":723.985,
        "New Zealand dollar":1.4558,
        "Oman Riyal":0.385,
        "Tanzanian Shilling":2344.103,
        "Ugandan Shilling":3708.5025,
        "United States Dollar":1,
        "South African Rand":14.3397,
        "Zambian Kwacha":12.029
        }

    variable=tk.StringVar(self.frame)
    variable.set(None)
    self.opt=tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, variable, *RATES, relief='raised', bd=2, width=8, bg='#008085')
    self.opt.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)



    self.master.mainloop()
```

cApp=MyApp()

Comment: Change to `*list(RATES.keys())`

Comment: It worked, thank you.!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by stovfl is correct, but leaving the rest of the config of the **OptionMenu** in the function gives errors because the initializer for an OptionMenu with a list of items is different. Therefore you have to do the config with a separate function:

```
    self.opt=tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, variable, *list(RATES.keys()))
    self.opt.config(relief='raised', bd=2, width=8, bg='#008085')
    self.opt.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem you can consider marking it as the answer.